Why is this JavaScript prototype inheritance returning undefined?
I've been racking my brain over this and can't figure out why the first console.log is returning undefined but the second one works fine. Any help would be much appreciated it's driving me crazy.
function Employee(title) {
    this.title = title;
}
Employee.prototype.setTitle = (title) => this.title = title;
Employee.prototype.getTitle = () => this.title;

function Engineer(title, isManager) {
    Employee.call(this, title);
    this.isManager = isManager;
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Engineer.prototype, Employee.prototype);

Engineer.prototype.setIsManager = (isManager) => {
    this.isManager = isManager;
};
Engineer.prototype.getIsManager = () => this.isManager;

function main() {
    const engineerObject = new Engineer('Developer', false);
    
    console.log(`Initial Employee Profile - Title is ${engineerObject.getTitle()}.`)
    // ---> why is engineerObject.getTitle() returning undefined here?

    engineerObject.setTitle('Manager');
    engineerObject.setIsManager(true);
    
    console.log(`Final Employee Profile - Title is ${engineerObject.getTitle()}. ${engineerObject.getIsManager() ? 'Is' : 'Is not'} a Manager\n`)
    // ---> works fine here though for some reason
}

main();


Arrow functions don’t have their own this. Note: separate function getters and setters, especially trivial ones, aren’t usually considered good practice in JavaScript (it has native support for getters and setters). Note 2: use class.

That was it - thank you! Learned something new
